# Identification of an insect from Bangladesh

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[This](https://youtu.be/5AcKShvVT98) is a video of the insect. Sorry, I don't have any still photograph.
Location: Savar, Bangladesh.

I've been suggested by an insect photographer that it is a caddisfly.

EDIT: Here are two images from the video
[image: unidentified insect]
[image]